# In DVCS with production and development branches, whats the master/default branch?

Tags: version-control

If your following the standard DVCS methodology of having a production branch and a development branch, I'm really interested in what do you do with the default (mercurial) or master (git) branch?

- Do you delete it (not recommended by several guides)?
- Do you use it as production?
- Do you use it as development?
- Or do you leave it empty and have separate dev and production branches?

Note: I'm really interested in Mercurial specifically, but any other DVCS or just general rules would be ok

Answer (score 4):

The practice used by git core and the kernel has been documented in the [gitworkflows manpage](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitworkflows.html). Another, more recent workflow is the [git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) workflow. Both recommend using master as the "production" branch.

Answer (score 2):

> Do you delete it (not recommended by
>   several guides)?

No.

> Do you use it as production?

No. Once a *state* of the code is deem production-ready, [git tag](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/02/03/tagging.html) is used to *mark* it.

> Do you use it as development?

Yes. The standard Git development way is for each developer to create a branch (locally) and do dev work specific to a **single** task. So, [mimicking those that have given Git presentations...](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8dhZ9BXQgc4)

"Create a branch. Work work work. Commit. Work work work. Commit. Merge. Push."

Once that issue has been finished, it is merged into the master branch and then pushed onto the master branch in the accessible repo. **Essentially - when viewing the workflow at the repo level - having all the dev work performed in the default/master branch.**

Comment: Thats one way I've seen with a few Git repos. Of course then in Github they have a monster branch list

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that your default branch is usually 'dev', and you create a new branch for each release (or tag, then branch when you need to bugfix). 'Prod' is just your most recent release. This is how we're planning on using Mercurial, although we're still pre-release.

Conceptually this make sense to me: a release is just a certain snapshot in time of your development process.

Edit: for a different take, see [A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

Comment: That's a ton of branches. I always thought you just tag and when you need to bugfix you checkout the tag, make changes, pull all the new updates, and merge. But anyway, interesting to see how you do it

Comment: I didn't write that very clearly. I was thinking more of branching for a major release, which you need to constantly patch. For example if you currently support v6.x and v7.x and are working on v8.x you'd have three live branches: 6, 7 and default. For point releases I agree that you'd tag and branch as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I asked myself the same question recently.

In our project, we maintain one branch for each major version of the application. I assume that these are the same as the "production branches" you are talking about. We call them "maintenance branches", here.

My first thought was to completely get rid of the `default` branch of mercurial, and have one branch for each major version. This would lead to this structure :

```
        branch   tag

    o     v2     2.2
  o |     v3
  | o     v2     2.1
  |/
  o       v2     2.0
  |
  | o     v1     1.1
  o |     v2
  | o     v1
  |/
  o       v1     1.0
  |
  o       v1
```

It works, but there is a downside to this approach : if you clone a repo like this, a simple `hg update` will do nothing, since the `default` branch doesn't exist anymore. Personnaly, I expect to be in the latest development state, after performing an `hg update`.

In the end, we chose this structure :

```
          branch             tag

    o     maintenance-V2     2.2
  o |     default
  | o     maintenance-V2     2.1
  |/
  o       default            2.0
  |
  | o     maintenance-V1     1.1
  o |     default
  | o     maintenance-V1
  |/
  o       default            1.0
  |
  o       default
```

The `default` branch is the development branch, and the other are version maintenance ones. Performing an `hg update` brings you to the latest `default` changeset, which is in this example the next V3.

Answer (score 0):

as answered here in different ways, and in some other ServerFault [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/189844/how-do-you-handle-the-default-branch-in-mercurial), you want to follow Mercurial guidelines [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/StandardBranching):

> 3 . The default branch
>
> This is where development of new features occurs. [...]
>
> (!) It is strongly recommended to do your primary development on the so-called 'default' branch, because it is the branch used by default in various commands such as clone.

The rest of article explains pretty well how to manage development Vs release branching.